# How to set TextBox Text when value selected from DropDown

Tags: php, jquery

I have a database table named tblCityState with the following data:

**CITY**  New York,Los Angeles,Atlanta

**STATE** New York,California,Georgia

I have a dropdown (ddCity) bound to the table (Select City from tblCityState).

When the user Selects "Los Angeles" from the DropDown, I want a textbox (tbState) to be populated with "California".

Now, I could set the value of the DropDown Item to be the State, but I want the Item value to be the City.

What is the best / easiest way to achive this../this is so much important for me..Please help me with some code.I searched everywhere but not get anything like that.I am new in php& ajax.suggest me some code.

Comment: Show what have you tried so far. then only we can help you

Comment: That is not how SO works. You've to show some research and effort on your part first. As a hint, I would recommend you to look into ajax

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$("#customer").autocomplete("state.php", {
        width: 160,
        autoFill: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });

$("#customer").blur(function() {
$("#customer1").val('');
$(".ac_results").next().css('height','0px');
var  vState = $("#customer").val();
        $("#customer1").autocomplete("city.php?state="+vState, {
            width: 160,
            autoFill: false,
            data:{},
            length:0,
        });
    });
});
</script>

<form name="thisForm1" method="post" id="thisForm1" action="" >
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="50%" align="center" class="ac_results">
<tr><td>
Enter state<input name="customer" type="text" id="customer"  value="" style="width:300px;" autocomplete="off"   >
</td><td>


Enter Keyword<input name="customer1" type="text" id="customer1"  value="" style="width:500px;" autocomplete="off" >
</td></tr>
</table>

</form>
```

state.php

```
<?php
$db = mysql_pconnect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('test',$db);
 $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);

$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state");
while($b = mysql_fetch_object($a))

{
echo "$b->name\n";
}




?>
```

city.php

```
<?php
$db = mysql_pconnect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('test',$db);
 $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
$vState = $_REQUEST['state'];

if (!empty($vState)) { 
    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM best_hotel WHERE class = '$vState'");
    while($b = mysql_fetch_object($a)) {
        echo "$b->name\n";
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: change the table names based on urs

Comment: textbox only there did u check.. its an auto complete

Comment: I want to select a city of a state from database.States are in dropdown list.after selecting it,textfield will display its city.Hope I am clear to all.

Comment: There you write your own query related to ur table